# Passing "this" in java constructor

Tags: java, constructor, this

Look into the following code:

```
public class ClassA {
    private boolean ClassAattr = false;

    public ClassA() {    
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler(this);
    }
}

public class ClassAHandler extends GeneralHandler {
    ClassA ca = null;

    public ClassAHandler(ClassA classa) {
        this.ca = classa;
    }
}
```

I need to access `ClassAattr` on some `ClassAHandler` methods, among other attributes. Is there a way to do so without passing the origin class in the handler constructor. I don't really like how this solution "looks".

Answer (score 12):

Passing `this` to another method/object from inside the constructor can be rather dangerous. Many guarantees that objects usually fulfill are not necessarily true, when they are looked at from inside the constructor.

For example if your class has a `final` (non-`static`) field, then you can usually depend on it being set to a value and never changing.

When the object you look at is currently executing its constructor, then that guarantee no longer holds true.

As an alternative you could delay the construction of the `ClassAHandler` object until it is first needed (for example by doing lazy initialization in the getter of that property).

Answer (score 3):

Create a registerHandler(ClassA handler) method.

There is no way to create a handler for something the handler doesn't know about.

Answer (score 3):

You could use inner classes, there is then a implicit parent-child relationship between the two instances. (But I don't know if it's really better).

```
public class ClassA {
    private boolean ClassAattr = false;

    public class ClassAHandler extends GeneralHandler {

       public ClassAHandler() {
           // can access ClassAattr
       }
    }

    public ClassA() {    
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler();
    }
}
```

If you pass `this`, the subclass will need to access the parent value with `parent.classAattr`. We can wonder whether it's correct according to the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Another option then would be that `ClassA` pass all the information that `ClassAHandler` requires in the constructor. If the handler requires the value of `ClassAttr`, pass it in the constructor.

```
    public ClassA() {    
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler( classAattr );
    }
```

But the parameter is passed by value so I don't know if it works for you.

A third option would be to change the design a bit and have the `boolean` be in the handler. Then `ClassA` accesses the value of the child with `handler.handlerAttr`. The child knows nothing about the parent, but the parent can access as much information in the child has he wants. This is better regarding the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

```
public class ClassAHandler extends GeneralHandler {     
   boolean handlerAttr;

   public ClassAHandler() {       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need the handler to have a reference to `ClassA`, but you don't want to set this up from within the constructor of `ClassA`? 
If that is the case, then you could separate construction from "wiring up" using a factory pattern, which will prevent your `ClassA` from needing to know about the `ClassAHandler` class.  Kind of like this:

```
public class ClassA {

    private boolean ClassAattr = false;

    public ClassA() {
    }

}


public class ClassAHandler {

    private ClassA ca = null;

    public ClassAHandler(ClassA classa) {
        this.ca = classa;
    }

}


public HandlerFactory {

    public ClassAHandler createClassAHandler(ClassA classa) {
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler(classa);
        return handler;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ClassA {
    private boolean ClassAattr = false;
        public ClassA() {    
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler(this);
        classAttr = true;
    }
}

public class ClassAHandler extends GeneralHandler {
    ClassA ca = null;

    public ClassAHandler(ClassA classa) {
        this.ca = classa;
        System.out.println(ca.classAttr);
    }
}
```

So I have added the statement `classAttr = true;`

The `System.out.println` statement will print ***false***.
This is because the construction of *`ClassA`* was not complete at that point.

So my suggestion is to add another method in *`classA`* which will create the *`ClassAHandler`* and then the *`classAHandler`* will receive fully constructed  *`ClassA`* object

So that the code will look like.

```
public class ClassA {
    private boolean ClassAattr = false;

    public ClassA() {    

        classAttr = true;
    }

    public init() {
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler(this);
    }
}
```

So that the code sequence will be `new ClassA().init()`
and will work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, passing `this` is dangerous because the `this` object has not finished running its constructor yet when it is received by the `ClassAHandler`. Instead you should do something like this, which is akin to the factory pattern:

```
public class ClassA {
    private boolean classAAttr = false;
    
    public static ClassA newInstance() {
        ClassA ca = new ClassA();
        new ClassAHandler(ca);
        return ca;
    }
    
    private ClassA() {}
}

public class ClassAHandler extends GeneralHandler {
    ClassA ca = null;
    
    public ClassAHandler(ClassA ca) {
        this.ca = ca;
    }
}
```

Of course now instead of writing `new ClassA()` in the rest of your code you need to use `ClassA.newInstance()`, but that's no real inconvenience.

I don't normally like the factory pattern, but I usually prefer this to the approaches in the other answers here because those require re-arranging your classes and inner classes in particular tend to complicate things. You also don't want to push extra responsibilities to the rest of your code and make it harder to set up new instances of `ClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

Write a getter method for ClassAattr, as

```
            public boolean isClassAattr(){
                 return this.ClassAattr;
            }
```

So that you can get access it as ca.isClassAattr();

Answer (score 0):

You may make ClassAHandler an inner class of ClassA. It would have access to the members of ClassA.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the code you pasted, however you can use a non static inner class to make things (arguably) cleaner:

```
public class ClassA {
    private boolean ClassAattr = false;

    public ClassA() {    
        ClassAHandler handler = new ClassAHandler();
    }

    class ClassAHandler extends GeneralHandler {

        // magically sees the instantiating ClassA members and methods
    }
}
```