# Passing this in constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I came across some JMS calling code that initializes the JMS session inside of its constructor. The calling code implements the ExceptionListener interface and passes a reference to *this* to the connection factory object, as shown below:

```
public class JmsCode implements ExceptionListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsCode.class);

    public JmsCode(String url, String username, String password, String trustStorePath, char[] trustStorePassword) throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(url);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setTrustStore(trustStorePath);
        connectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword(new String(trustStorePassword));
        connectionFactory.setExceptionListener(this);

        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Unexpected JMS exception caught", e);
    }

}
```

I am wondering if it is safe to pass a reference to *this* from the JmsCode constructor given that the object hasn't been fully constructed yet. I came across a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419410/passing-this-in-java-constructor) which had me reading up on [IBM's article on not publishing *this* during construction](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html#2). While I agree with their reasoning, I am not sure if it applies in this case since the only thing the exception listener is doing is logging via a static and final member. Is the code above safe (ignoring someone else being tempted to change the exception listener method to use some instance state of the object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact unsafe publishing, and it's theoretically possible for another object to see this one in an inconsistent state.

That said, while this isn't a good pattern (and it's just shown here to demonstrate `ExceptionListener`), the logic of the constructor shows that the class is in fact fully constructed by the time that the `this` reference escapes (because it has nothing to construct), and so in this exact case there's nothing that can go wrong.

Comment: Could something go wrong if another thread, started by the factory object, tried to call the onException method on this? This is obviously hypothetical since I don't expect that to happen here but it may change how we implement further logic down the road.

Comment: @Hmmmmm *In general*, yes, something could go wrong. *In this particular case*, there is nothing to go wrong (no state to be inconsistent). Note that "down the road", you will probably be using a container such as Spring to handle things like JMS connection management, and you certainly would split up the connection management and your exception handler into separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is safe or not depends on where that reference to `this` can escape *to*. If, as a consequence of this call, `this` could be read by another thread, then it is not safe.

If you want to ensure an instance is completely initialized for safe publication *and* you want to publish it, a constructor isn't the right place to publish it. Instead, you'll need to create a Factory object or a static factory method which can construct the object safely and then publish it before returning it to the caller.

Comment: Valid point. I actually removed a lot of the code to make it easier to read (and to not get in trouble for posting our code). The constructor is private and called from an old-school double lock check getInstance method.

Answer (score -1):

It is completely safe. You are just passing the `this` reference, not using anything in the `this` scope.

Something will go wrong on that iff the `.setExceptionListener(this)` method performs something else than being a setter.

Comment: My fear is exactly what you mentioned, if setExceptionListener does more than just being a setter. Let's say, hypothetically, that the local JMS client is already in a bad state and this info is cached somewhere so there is an immediate knowledge of an exception. Let's also say that, in another thread, it immediately tries to call the onException function, before the constructor had completed. What would the behavior be?